# Looking for a literature algo for extimating network flows

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Let's say I have a network of nodes in which each nodes are represented by point in a plane ( 2D space). Let's say we have a metric of this space ( ie is actually a euclidean space ), and each node is connected to the ones adiacent to it: think as a **grid of squares**. In each square we can measure, at intervals, a count of individuals. Does exists a literature algorithm for extimating the flow between each square, standing that individuals can move at a finite speed?

Answer (score 1):

Can individuals be created or destroyed? If they can, this is impossible, because there are multiple solutions that have different values for the numbers created and destroyed.

If the time interval is greater than the time to move between adjacent nodes this will be impossible, because there are multiple solutions, corresponding to the multiple routes that can be followed.

Your best aporoach is likely to consider a *sub set* of all candidate solutions, described by a finite set of parameters, with a *badness* function computed from the candidate that has those parameters. The *badness* function must be smaller for candidates that you consider to be closer to the correct solution. The problem then becomes a multi dimensional minimisation problem: searching for the parameter values of the candidate that gives the minimum value for the *badness* function. There are several well known algorithms for solving those kinds of problems.

Your badness function will have to introduce additional constraints, such as preferring solutions with smaller numbers created and destroyed, and preferring smaller network flows.

Comment: Yes I know it will be a multiple solution, but the request is an estimate, not a correct solution